# PHP table problem

Tags: php, mysql

Im want to create a table that show the values of a mysql table. The problem is that when I open the page I only have the columns name. But I dont see any row. I also want to make a hyperlink of each row. How I will do that.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  include_once 'rnheader.php';  
  echo '</br>';

  echo '<a href = "rnservices.php">  Create Service</a> ';

  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th>Service ID</th>';
  echo '<th>Title</th>';
  echo '<th>Description</th>';
  echo '<th>Notes</th>';
  echo '<th>Submit By</th>';
  echo '<th>Assigned Employee</th>';
  echo '<th>Assigned Group</th>';
  echo '<th>Category</th>';
  echo '<th>Status</th>';
  echo '<th>Urgency</th>';
  echo '<th>Customer</th>';
  echo '<th>Day Created</th>';
  echo '</tr>';

  $query = ("SELECT ServiceID, Title, Description, Notes, "
          ."                   SubmitBy, AssignedEmp, AssignedGroup, "
          ."                   NameCategory, TipoStatus, TiposUrgencia, "
          ."                   CustomerName, DayCreation "
          ."FROM    Service");

  $result = queryMysql($query);
  echo 'Number of Rows: ' . mysql_num_rows($result);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ServiceID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Notes'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['SubmitBy'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['AssignedEmp'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['AssignedGroup'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['NameCategory'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['TipoStatus'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['TiposUrgencia'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['CustomerName'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['DayCreation'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }

  mysqli_free_result($result);
  echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Does mysql_error() show anything?

Comment: the mysqli_fetch_assoc was my mistake. But a can create a hyperlink of each row?

Comment: You are not closing the table... You should look into the generated HTML code first.

Comment: I reformatted your code, but not sure if I eliminated problems too. There were several `<p></p>` tags in there I assumed for your attempt at formatting, which I have removed. That being said, after the reformat, this code looks functional...

Comment: You're echoing the row count in the middle of the table, which is bad html. Take out that echo 'Number of Rows' statement and put it after the closing tag of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//not tested
<p>
include_once 'rnheader.php';  
</p>
<p>
echo '<a href = "rnservices.php">  Create Service</a> ';
</p>

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Service ID</th>';
echo '<th>Title</th>';
echo '<th>Description</th>';
echo '<th>Notes</th>';
echo '<th>Submit By</th>';
echo '<th>Assigned Employee</th>';
echo '<th>Assigned Group</th>';
echo '<th>Category</th>';
echo '<th>Status</th>';
echo '<th>Urgency</th>';
echo '<th>Customer</th>';
echo '<th>Day Created</th>';
echo '</tr>';


$query = ("SELECT ServiceID, Title, Description, Notes, SubmitBy, AssignedEmp, " .
"AssignedGroup, NameCategory, TipoStatus, TiposUrgencia, CustomerName, DayCreation FROM Service");

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

//use results
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['ServiceID'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Notes'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['SubmitBy'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['AssignedEmp'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['AssignedGroup'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['NameCategory'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['TipoStatus'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['TiposUrgencia'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['CustomerName'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['DayCreation'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}   
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following along with this [datagrid tutorial](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2971-PHP-Display-MySQL-database-query-data-in-an-HTML-grid.html) will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

To make a field of the row into a link, you can do something like this:

`echo '<td><a href="whateverpage?id='.$row['ServiceId'].'">'. $row['Title'] . '</a></td>';`

Comment: Hello how I can create a variable from that link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sort of thing for the hyperlinks.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dduncan/FQwKR/1/

Comment: How I can make the selected link into a php variable to open the form of the select service?